# Editing a sequence of fields in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file like this:

```
INSERT INTO `example`
(`name`, `location`, `height`)
VALUES
('A', '', ''),
('B', '', ''),
('C', '', '');
```

I want to fill in the middle set of quote marks (the ones under `location`) so that I end up with

```
INSERT INTO `example`
(`name`, `location`, `height`)
VALUES
('A', 'one',   ''),
('B', 'two',   ''),
('C', 'three', '');
```

What's a good way to do that? Aligning the third column of quotes isn't necessary, but preferred.

Comment: Where's the 'one,two,three' coming from? Are you typing it, pasting it, from another file, etc?

Comment: @KennyYounger: Typing it. I'm trying to avoid having to navigate character-by-character to align my cursor with the middle column of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a similar approach to *rush*, but remaining more in insert mode:

<kbd>/''/e</kbd> lands you in between the quotes.

<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>one</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> <kbd>2n</kbd>

<kbd>two</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> <kbd>2n</kbd>

<kbd>three</kbd>

#### Update

As for aligning the columns I would suggest using Dr. Chip's `Align` plugin,  then a simple `:'<,'>Align ,` would put the columns right.

Comment: What's `/e` in the first command? (Or, even better, where can I find the documentation for it?)

Comment: `e` means set cursor at the end of the match. This is the offset specification, you can go back, forward, up, and down. It's documented as `search-offset`.

Comment: Comes in very handy when using the search as a motion for an operator, e.g. delete until `pattern`: `d/pattern/-1`. Or delete until pattern + 2 lines: `d/pattern/2`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>gg</kbd> # will jump to the first string

<kbd>/'',</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> # will jump to the first `''` occurence

<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>one</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> # will add `one` into `''` into second column

<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> # will jump to the third column and add `Tab` if necessary. optional step

<kbd>n</kbd> #this will move you to line 2

Comment: The `n` should be doubled or `2n`.

Comment: nope. As you can mention, the search pattern includes comma at the end. And it will match only the second column. Therefore I need only one `n`.

Comment: Ah I see, you're right.